# How to access auth data in unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, authentication, oauth, jasmine, phantomjs

I'm learning how to test the client side (e.g. when you click some button, it should happen something).

I am using [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/) and [Phantom](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) to test the client side, doing something like this (it's more or less pseudo-code, just as example):

```
describe("testing front-end", function () {
  it("should do something when clicking some button", function (done) {
      openPageInPhantom("my-page", function () {
          this.find("my-button").click();
          expect(something).toBe(happened);
          done();
      });
   });
});
```

This works fine when no authentication is needed. What I do not understand is how to handle authentication in tests.

So, let's suppose the button I have to click is only visible for logged in users. So, first we need to login.

- How to handle basic authentication?

  Is storing the username and password in the tests a good practice? I saw answers on StackOverflow recommending that and others saying that [it should be done differently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047939/1420197).
- How to handle OAuth in tests?

  If the content (in my case the example button) is accessible after logging in via a provider (e.g. Twitter) and it only appears after some data coming from the login provider come in the database, I have no idea how to do that with OAuth. I did see many answers saying that *you should not test others' code but yours*.

Comment: If you do a complete integration testing I think the most simple way to do it is to setup a test account, storing/using username and password for it in tests will be ok, the same with Twitter - create a test account. The other way is to define what your application requires from a user to consider him authenticated - usually it is a cookie - so let serverside generate a cookie for you before tests start and then send this cookie with requests which require authorization.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov Oh, I see! So, it's basically complete simulation of a user on the website: clicking the Twitter sign in button, then redirect to Twitter sign in form, fill the form and redirect back to the website. Is this the *good way* to do it? I have no previous experience in unit testing on the client (I wrote only tests for some of my libraries to test their functionalities). Thanks!